# Is a file Overlay a security threat?

Tags: security, hashing, internet-security, checksum, overlay

How do you tell if the "Overlay" found on some files when searching the hash checksum on VirusTotal poses any threat?

Would the Overlay be part of the signed file?  Does the VT page information, and the checksum, exclude anything in the Overlay?

VT says: "maybe some additional malicious payload" in the mouseover description of "Overlay". Is this a common issue?

Comment: In general, overlays are not necessarily a threat, but are an uncommon memory loading technique, which should be scrutinized.  Typically, overlays are not signed, but could be if the loader strips the signature, or the placement in memory ignores the signature.  Overlays can include instructions and/or data -- it depends upon where (in memory) the overlay gets loaded, and how the loader handles the overlay.  It's much easier for anti-virus products to evaluate overlays when they are loaded in-memory by the loader.  For more info, [see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlay_(programming))

Comment: Thanks for all that info, if it is uncommon does that imply that I would maybe need to consider it an potential issue when downloading an unfamiliar program, but not so much if downloading from say Libre/Open office, or getting Microsoft files, an antivirus, a browser, or drivers from a manufacturer etc.

Comment: Yes, I would agree with your assessment.  Certain games can also use overlays, due to the large amount of data and improved loading speed that overlays can provide.  This is probably obvious, but just be sure you trust your vendors, try to validate file downloads against vendor-provided hashes, executables should be digitally signed, always scan new content offline as much as possible before use, and try to run a modern on-access/on-execute anti-virus scanner with recent updates at run-time.  Rinse, repeat.

Comment: @lee Thanks for your helpful reply, "modern on-access/on-execute anti-virus scanner " does that include free scanners like Avast, Windows Defender etc, or only certain paid for scanners?  I've read hashes can be changed at the same time as a file, I'm looking into GPG to verify signitures. Wondering if that's overkill though. Once I have the key etc downloaded can I use GPG offline, or does it need internet?

Comment: The phrase "you get what you pay for" applies to AV.  These free scanners may be fine for technical users, but not typically home users.  Always use the largest hash available from vendors for file verification (SHA256 minimum, if possible).  GPG can work offline if CRL/OCSP checks are not needed.